# How to return datetimeoffset table columns into custom set?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

== UPDATE ==

The problem seems to be related to any dataset that has a combination of NULL values and valid datetimes. I have modified the TVF to ensure all datetimes are wrapped in a CAST(? as datetimeoffset) and it still doesn't work!

If I default the NULL dates to '0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' then everything works.

== ORIGINAL ==

How can I return datetimeoffset SQL data columns into my custom set using entity framework FromSqlInterpolated method?

I have the following custom IQueryable on my DbContext where tvfTaskSourceFormRequest is a Table Value Function: -

```
        public IQueryable<ClientAppTask> TaskSourceChecklist(int companyId, int userId)
        {
            return Set<ClientAppTask>().FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM dbo.tvfTaskSourceChecklist({companyId},{userId})");
        }
```

and the ClientAppTask class is defined as: -

```
    public class ClientAppTask
    {
        public int TaskType { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Reference { get; set; }
        public string ContextReference { get; set; }
        public string ContextTitle { get; set; }
        public string ContextSubTitle { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? Scheduled { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? Deadline { get; set; }
    }
```

The table value function is returning data correctly if I select rows using it within sql management studio so the data is there for Scheduled and Deadline, example data: -

```
TaskType    Id  Reference   ContextReference    ContextTitle    ContextSubTitle Scheduled   Deadline
1   1   NULL        Test Bakery Low Risk Coding Record Check Service    NULL    NULL
1   1   NULL        Test Bakery Low Risk Coding Record Check Service    2021-09-13 14:00:00.0000000 +00:00  2021-09-13 15:00:00.0000000 +00:00
1   1   NULL        Test Bakery Low Risk Coding Record Check Service    2021-09-13 20:00:00.0000000 +00:00  2021-09-13 21:00:00.0000000 +00:00
```

But when I look at the data returned by entity framework core v3.1.19 within my set when called using: -

```
        private async Task<List<ClientAppTask>> FetchTaskChecklist(int companyId, int userId)
        {
            return await _oltp.TaskSourceChecklist(companyId, userId).ToListAsync();
        }
```

All of my Deadline and Scheduled datetimeoffset values are null?

TVF script for completeness: -

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[tvfTaskSourceChecklist] (
    @companyId int,
    @userId int
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
    SELECT
        1 AS TaskType,
        CSE.Id,
        CS.Reference,
        E.Reference AS ContextReference,
        E.Title AS ContextTitle,
        CS.Title AS ContextSubTitle,
        CAST(CRIO.UtcTime as datetimeoffset) AS Scheduled,
        CAST(CASE CSEC.ResponseIntervalMinutes 
            WHEN NULL THEN NULL
            ELSE DATEADD(mi, CSEC.ResponseIntervalMinutes, CRIO.UtcTime)
        END as datetimeoffset) AS Deadline
    FROM tblChecklistServiceEnrolment AS CSE
    INNER JOIN tblChecklistService AS CS ON CSE.ChecklistServiceId=CS.Id
    INNER JOIN tblChecklistDefinition AS CD ON CS.ChecklistDefinitionId=CD.Id
    INNER JOIN tvfEntitiesForChecklist(@companyId, @userId) AS EFU ON CSE.EntityId=EFU.EntityId
    INNER JOIN tblEntity AS E ON EFU.EntityId=E.Id
    INNER JOIN tblProxyCompany AS PC ON E.CompanyId=PC.Id
    INNER JOIN tblChecklistResponseInterval AS CRI ON CS.Id=CRI.ChecklistServiceId
    LEFT JOIN tblChecklistResponseIntervalOffset AS CRIO ON CRI.Id=CRIO.ResponseIntervalId AND ((E.LocalTimeZoneId IS NOT NULL AND E.LocalTimeZoneId=CRIO.TimeZoneId) OR (PC.DefaultTimeZoneId IS NOT NULL AND PC.DefaultTimeZoneId=CRIO.TimeZoneId OR 47=CRIO.TimeZoneId))
    LEFT JOIN tblChecklistServiceEscalation AS ESC ON CS.Id=ESC.ChecklistServiceId AND ESC.EscalationMode=0 AND ESC.Deleted=0
    LEFT JOIN tblChecklistServiceEscalationCriteria AS CSEC ON ESC.Id=CSEC.EscalationId AND CSEC.Deleted=0 AND CSEC.CriteriaMode=0
    WHERE
        CD.CompanyId=@companyId AND
        CS.Deleted=0 AND
        CS.[Enabled]=1 AND
        CSE.Deleted=0 AND
        CSE.[Enabled]=1 AND
        CRI.Deleted=0 AND
        CRI.[Status]=0
    UNION
    SELECT
        1 AS TaskType,
        CSE.Id,
        CS.Reference,
        E.Reference AS ContextReference,
        E.Title AS ContextTitle,
        CS.Title AS ContextSubTitle,
        CAST(NULL as datetimeoffset) AS Scheduled,
        CAST(NULL as datetimeoffset) AS Deadline
    FROM tblChecklistServiceEnrolment AS CSE
    INNER JOIN tblChecklistService AS CS ON CSE.ChecklistServiceId=CS.Id
    INNER JOIN tblChecklistDefinition AS CD ON CS.ChecklistDefinitionId=CD.Id
    INNER JOIN tvfEntitiesForChecklist(@companyId, @userId) AS EFU ON CSE.EntityId=EFU.EntityId
    INNER JOIN tblEntity AS E ON EFU.EntityId=E.Id
    WHERE
        CD.CompanyId=@companyId AND
        CS.Deleted=0 AND
        CS.[Enabled]=1 AND
        CS.AllowAdhoc=1 AND
        CSE.Deleted=0 AND
        CSE.[Enabled]=1
);
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Mapping `DateTimeOffset` just works. You didn't post the DbContext configuration, the TVF code or the actual C# code, so it's impossible to even guess what's wrong. What is `TaskSourceChecklist()` and how is it related to `TaskSourceFormRequest()` ?

Comment: Do you get back three rows in your method as well? All the `Id`s being the same value looks fishy, if it ends up being used as a key.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry I grabbed the wrong bit of code, I have updated the example to be consistent and I have added the TVF script.

Comment: @JeroenMostert the Id is correct and not being used as a key.

Comment: OK I've just built a simple out of context test and it's working as I would expect so something is wrong somewhere. I'll report back when I find the issue just in case it helps anybody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was identified by @jeroenmostert but I foolishly dismissed it!

My TVF does a load of heavy lifting on the SQL Server and returns a list of tasks. Because the TVF is not yet finished and because the TVF is returning records from several sources there is no primary key!

Entity framework manages the data loaded and by convention uses the Id column to determine whether a record is the same as another. Hence when loading the records from my TVF entity framework was merging them so the resulting data was whatever the last record was with that Id.

To prevent this unwanted behaviour in this instance you can use the `HasNoKey()` method which does exactly what it says, configures that model set as having no key.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   modelBuilder.Entity<ClientAppTask>().HasNoKey();
}
```

Comment: For the record, I've never used EF in practice, so I had no idea it has this behavior, otherwise I would have pointed it (and the solution) out directly, of course.